# Mongo aggregation with $lookup not working when using let

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this in a `collectionA`:

```
{ 
    "catalogId" : "17582"
}
```

And documents like this in a `collectionB`:

```
{ 
    "product" : {
       "catalogId" : "17582"
}
```

I'm applying the following aggregation to `collectionA`:

```
{
    $lookup: {
     from: "collectionB",
     let: {
        catalogId: "$catalogId"
      },
      pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
                "product.catalogId": "$$catalogId"
            }
          }         
      ],
      as: "something"
   }
}
```

But I'm having an empty result. Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query has to be like below, check this [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)  for ref :

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "collectionB",
        let: {
            catalogId: "$catalogId"
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: { $eq: ["$product.catalogId", "$$catalogId"] }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "something"
    }
}])
```